# Copy matching line to new file

Tags: text, text-editor, replace

Hi I'm using EmEditor because I have huge log files and it handles them quite well.

The question is...

Is there a way for me to find any line the has a specific word and create (copy just that line) to a new file.
The other way to do this this would be to find every line that does not have a specific word and delete that line.

Reason: The log files are huge and I only need to look at a log of say one folder or page on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a scripting language such as Python to parse the files.